# Selector in jQuery working in an unintuitive way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector as follows.

```
subMenus.children("li.tab").children("a").each(function () { ... }
```

It works as supposed to. Then, I read on the [website](https://api.jquery.com/children/) that the following is also supposed to work (and since it's more compact, I prefer it that way).

```
subMenus.children("li.tab>a").each(function () { ... }
```

However, the latter seems not to find any elements as the action in the squiglies doesn't execute. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Markup as requested.

```
<ul id="submenu1" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu2" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu3" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And using `li.tab > a` to keep with the original, working code?

Comment: @nicovank Corrected typo.

Comment: `.children()` would only select direct children. So `subMenus.children("li.tab>a")` would select anchor tags that are direct children of `subMenus`, and also direct children of `li.tab`. Here you can use `.find()` instead. `subMenus.find(">li.tab>a").each()`

Comment: @Alex.S Oh, darn. I just realized the problem. Thanks! Post it as a reply so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **find()**.

Technically `"li.tab > a"` is not a *"child"* of **subMenus**

```js
$(".tabs").find("li.tab>a").each(function () { console.log(this); });
```

```html
<ul id="submenu1" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu2" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu3" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A child combinator in CSS is the "greater than" symbol, it looks like this:

```
ol > li {
  color: red;
}
```

It means "select elements that are direct descendants only". In this case: "select list items that are direct descendants of an ordered list". To illustrate:

```
<ol>
  <li>WILL be selected</li>
  <li>WILL be selected</li>
  <ul>
     <li>Will NOT be selected</li>
     <li>Will NOT be selected</li>
  </ul>
  <li>WILL be selected</li>
</ol>
```

Try removing the > symbol.

```
$("li.tab a");
```

The first jQuery selector is looking for children of your `<li/>` (including grandchildren).

```
$("li.tab").children("a");
```

Whereas your second jQuery selector is looking for direct children of your `<li/>` (NOT including grandchildren).

```
$("li.tab > a");
```

**Update:**
You'll want to use .find instead of .children because

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: I think that's the error. [Here is a fiddle](http://codepen.io/nicovank/pen/LbyxoK) to illustrate.

Comment: The thing is that those **are** the direct descendants. *ul -> li -> a*

Comment: Could you update your question with an HTML structure for reference?

Comment: @Daerik Sure thing. Take a look.

Comment: @nicovank The fiddle shows something else than I meant to show. Try to paste in the HTML from my question and the following two JS. One works, the other doesn't. *$(".tabs").children("li>a").each(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "red");
});
$(".tabs").children("li").children("a").each(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "red");
});*

Comment: I'm not sure if I explain it correctly. The *children()* method works **but** I need to use two nested ones. In the docs it's said that I can push in a selector into it. And *li>a* **is** a selector, isn't it?

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten Thanks for the HTML. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I just got it. Tricky thing... +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

`.children()` would only select direct children. So `subMenus.children("li.tab>a")` would select anchor tags that are direct children of `subMenus`, and also direct children of `li.tab`.

Here you can use `.find()` instead: `subMenus.find(">li.tab>a").each()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
subMenus.children("li.tab>a").each(function () { ... }
```

Comment: I corrected the typo in the question. That's the code that I have. Sadly.

Comment: What is subMenus defined as?  ie- do you have a preceeding line like var subMenus = $("ul#subMenus") or something like that?

Comment: It's *var subMenus = $(".tabs");*. And those are *ul*.